# window onscroll change menu link style

Tags: jquery, css, styles, scrollto, onscroll

I am trying to use the window scroll function so that a menu link will change its style to the relevant section the user has scrolled to.

I have it to alert the user once they scroll to the portfolio section. But how about the style of a link?

Code is a little out of my league:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var aPortfolio = $('.portfoliowrapper').height();
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=aPortfolio){
        alert('portfolio just passed.');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
if($(this).scrollTop()>=aPortfolio){
    alert('portfolio just passed.');
    $("yourlink").css({
        // Whatever styles you want here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a class which overrides the link styles and add/remove it:

**CSS**

```
.linkPortfolio {
    // styles
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  var $targetAnchor = $('#linkID');

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var aPortfolio = $('.portfoliowrapper').height();
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=aPortfolio){
        alert('portfolio just passed.');
        $targetAnchor.addClass('linkPortfolio');
    } else {
        $targetAnchor.removeClass('linkPortfolio');
    }
  });
});
```